# Excel Match / Index - Fill in blank cells based on two other cells matching

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to fill in blank cells with valued cells based on matching cells in two different worksheets.

[MasterCAP Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8giy.png)

[BESTRFS Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuNil.png)

The cells in MasterCAP[RFS_ID] must be filled in with the value in BESTRFS[BEST_RFS] when MasterCAP[CAP] cell matches a BESTRFS[ACAP] cell. For example, MasterCap A2 would fill in with "134" because the CAP fields both match to "H.3"

NOTES
Using Excel 2016.

There are more columns and rows than shown in the example.

Columns and Rows will be added, deleted, and rearranged during work. So the CAP column may not always be column B.

Rows are sorted quite often.

I have attempted Index / Match but am making quite a mess of it. (I keep getting value errors.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your desired output:
 [image: output]

Used index match for this:

> =INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(B6,F:F,0))